# Problems panning large svg in PaperJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, paperjs

```js
var path = new Path.Circle({
  center: view.center,
  radius: 10,
  strokeColor: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 3,
  applyMatrix: false,
  strokeScaling: false
});

var svgItem;

project.importSVG("https://svgshare.com/getbyhash/sha1-yxefOEotn9oAUgg+1qfc5gNw4Bs=", {
  onLoad : function (item) {
    item.center = view.center;
    svgItem = item;
  }
});

console.log(svgItem);

tool.onMouseMove = function(event) {
  //on mouse move the position of 'path' var changes to underneath cursor again
  path.position = event.point;
  //console.log(event.point); //debug
}

var toolSize = document.getElementById("tool");

console.log(toolSize);
toolSize.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  console.log("Radius slider change detected! " + event.target.value + ". path.radius is: " + path.bounds.width);
  //path.radius = event.target.value;
  path.scaling = this.value;
});

tool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
  //test to see of the shift key was held whilst a mouse drag action was peformed
  if (event.modifiers.shift)
  {
    //move the image the distance of the mouse drag
    svgItem.position = view.center + event.delta;
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#opts {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10vw;
  bottom: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.8/paper-full.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="svg_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="opts">
    <input id="tool" type="range" name="tool" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="1" id="toolSize" />
    <input id="smooth" type="range" name="flatten" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="1" id="smooth" />
    <input id="flatten" type="range" name="flatten" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="1" id="flatten" />
  </div>
  <main>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
  </main>
  <script type="text/paperscript" src="paper_script.js" canvas="canvas">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can't actually get my example to work anywhere except for on **localhost** but I have a large SVG inside of my paperJS canvas which extends out past the canvas bounds.

When I try to pan it by pressing shift and dragging the mouse the svg moves but ultimately snaps to a specific position and responds but always pings back to this place after that

Comment: Please, replace `http://localhost:8080/PCB-trace.svg` with a path to the file you intend to use. You can try using a service like https://svgur.com/ to host the file.

Comment: `I can't actually get my example to work`  Looks like SO snippets are down atm.  For me I'm getting a 503 (service unavailable).

Comment: Snippet can't work, since you make a call to `http://localhost:8080/`. Please refactor your code so as to make it reproducible.

Comment: @NinoFiliu  Snippets are down full stop, the `http://localhost:8080/` is of course a problem when snippets are up an running.

Comment: @Keith indeed, thanks for the info. Your comment was not yet available when i made mine.

Comment: I tried to add a remote hosted svg through the link given by @IsmaelMiguel but it now comes up with 3 errors I don't really understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
svgItem.position = view.center + event.delta;
```

Inside of a `mousedrag` event handler function, `event.delta` is actually representing the vector between the last point and the current point. You were wrongly calculating the desired position by simply adding this vector to view center point.

What you want to do instead, is add this vector to item current position.

```
svgItem.position += event.delta;
```

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/VVLBbsIwDP0VqxdAsMCFSxEndp00absBhyxxqaFNqiQtmxD/PieFrqtUVc57fnl+7i0zssYszz4uGFSZLTJldayXS9BOXkGCIqcqPLiD6aQDCljDFgxe4V2GUuwSOr1FHPhRaAK6HDrCq+iLxRNzUlPrc1ivhqOCqmpnK8sdE+ukOeEkQvfZJn7iy0asgdq2HqOjkxAiHhetUYEYseYtYq8MTbHjC2cwmOFeplMBvqQiAHloHHqP+iESOYz2faK2mgpC50Wij3T+tGrbYcpgDMVaNNZTMjTfQq+nsQpy8yTe01yjqTT5ppI/QMYH16ZhfIRStJZM+MTvMArWcpYmcE5phsdI0uiUCgQLyVso8bGxyRByE9X+rQTmsF8t4GW9Og6sc+sDz69kdMLX9MznOvjP+HIoL0nLZ/n+eP8F) demonstrating the solution.

```
// draw a circle
var item = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

// on mouse drag...
function onMouseDrag(event) {
    // ...if shift is pressed...
    if (event.modifiers.shift) {
        // ...move item
        item.position += event.delta;
    }
}

// display instructions
new PointText({
    content: 'press shift and drag to move the circle',
    point: view.center + [0, -50],
    justification: 'center'
});
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly why it was giving me the behaviour it did but thankyou nonetheless!